# Adding a power curve to scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, scatter-plot

I want to add a power curve with confidence intervals to my diamter-weight relationship, which clearly follows a y=a*x^b regression. So far, I used the geom_smooth "loess" version, but this is not yet quite right and perfect. Any suggestion how to add a power regression line would be much appreciated. Below is the used code:

```
p2<-ggplot(Data,aes(x=Diameter,y=Wet_weight,colour=Site))+
  geom_point(size=3.5,alpha=0.3)+
  geom_smooth(aes(group=Species),method=loess,colour="black")+
  labs(x="\nUmbrella diamter (mm)",y="Wet weight (mg)\n")+theme_classic()+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black","dark blue","blue","dark green","green"))+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=20),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=18,colour="black"),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=20),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=18,colour="black"),
        axis.ticks=element_line(colour="black",size=1),
        axis.line=element_line(colour="black",size=1,linetype="solid"),
        legend.position=c(0.18,0.75),
        legend.text=element_text(colour="black",size=17),
        legend.title=element_text(colour="black",size=18))
p2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add a piece of code and (dummy) data with how you would do the power regression outside of ggplot2?

Answer (score 1):

I used this to get many equations, R2, and plots.

```
df= #change your data frame so it fits the current code
variables=c("group","year") #if you have multiple groups/seasons/years/elements add them here
df$y= #which variable will be your y 
df$x= #which variable will be your x 

#No changes get the equations
text=df %>% 
  group_by(across(all_of(variables))) %>% #your grouping variables 
  do(broom::tidy(lm(log(y) ~ log(x), data = .))) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(y = round(ifelse(term=='(Intercept)',exp(estimate),estimate),digits = 2)) %>%  #your equation values rounded to 2
  select(-estimate,-std.error,-statistic     ,-p.value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = term,values_from = y) %>% 
  rename(.,a=`(Intercept)`,b=`log(x)`) 
#CHANGE before running!! add your grouping variables
rsq=df %>%
  split(list(.$group,.$year)) %>% #---- HERE add the names after $
  map(~lm(log(y) ~ log(x), data = .)) %>%
  map(summary) %>%
  map_dbl("r.squared") %>% 
  data.frame() 
#Join the R2 and y results for the plot in a single data frame and write the equations
labels.df=mutate(rsq,groups=row.names(rsq)) %>% 
  separate(col = groups,into = c(variables),sep = "[.]",
         convert = TRUE, remove = T, fill = "right") %>% 
  rename("R"='.') %>% 
  left_join(text,.) %>% 
  mutate(R=round(R,digits = 4), #round your R2 digits
    eq= paste('y==',a,"~x^(",b,")", sep = ""),
         rsql=paste("R^2==",R),
         full= paste('y==',a,"~x^(",b,")","~~R^2==",R, sep = ""))
# plot 
ggplot(df,aes(x = x,y = y)) +
  geom_point(size=4,mapping = aes(
    colour=factor(ifelse(is.na(get(variables[2])),"",(get(variables[2])))), #points colour
    shape=get(variables[1]))) + # different shapes
  facet_wrap(get(variables[1])~ifelse(is.na(get(variables[2])),"",get(variables[2])),
             scales = "free",labeller = labeller(.multi_line = F))+ #for multiple groups; join text in one line
  stat_smooth(mapping=aes(colour=get(variables[1])), #colours for our trend
              method = 'nls', formula = 'y~a*x^b', 
              method.args = list(start=c(a=1,b=1)),se=FALSE) +
  geom_text(labels.df,x = Inf, y = Inf,size=5, mapping = aes(label = (eq)), parse = T,vjust=1, hjust=1)+
  geom_text(labels.df,x = Inf,y = Inf,size=5, mapping = aes(label = (rsql)), parse = T,vjust=2.5, hjust=1)+
  #scale_y_log10() + #add this to avoid problems with big y values
  labs(x="Your x label",y="your y label")+
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        strip.background = element_rect(fill="#b2d6e2"))
```